# Socket.IO emitting chat message to room

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I currently have a system in socketio that creates rooms for individual messaging:

```
  socket.on("chat message", function(msg) {
    var roomname;
    if (msg.recipient > msg.sender) {
        roomname = msg.sender + "-" + msg.recipient;
    }
    else {
        roomname = msg.recipient + "-" + msg.sender;
    }
    if(!io.sockets.adapter.sids[users[msg.sender]][roomname]) {
        socket.join(roomname);
    }
    var clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomname].sockets;
    console.log(clients);
    io.in(roomname).emit("chat message", msg);
});
```

The if/else statement basically creates the roomname (person1-person2) in alphabetic order to prevent confusion when both parties join the room. The socket joins this room if it is not already in it. This is all triggered when the server receives "chat message". I have confirmed that the socket room joining part works. However, I seem to not be getting the message on the client end:

```
var socket = io();
socket.on("chat message", function(msg) {
    alert("received message");
    console.log(msg[message]);
    if (msg[message] != "") {
        $(".chat-history-div").append($("<li>").text(msg.message));
    }
});
```

I am not receiving the alert "received message" when I send a message. Why is this? Why am I not receiving a message from the server? Thanks!

EDIT:
This is my client side `emit("chat message)`:

```
 var socket = io();
 $("#form-send-message").submit(function () {
     var messageDetails = {
        sender: "<%=currentUser.username%>",
        recipient: $(this).find("textarea").val(),
        message: $(this).find(".chat-message-input").val()
    }
    socket.emit("chat message", messageDetails);
    $(".chat-message-input").val("");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you show us your client side `emit("chat message")`? I'm not seeing anything wrong with the code provided if this is true: *I have confirmed that the socket room joining part works*

Comment: Does the browser's developer console show any error?

Comment: Are you getting the output of console.log(clients); I think error comes when you try to find number of clients in room and code after that is not getting executed try putting another console.log() after that line and check the output

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande I added the client side chat message emit

Comment: @MehulPrajapati I moved the `console.log(clients)` to after the `io.in(roomname).emit` and I am still getting the same things logged to the console and the message is still not sending/working

Comment: Is socket.join(roomname) working try putting console.log inside that condition and one thing will work or not but try this put io.in(roomname).emit inside settimeout of 2000.

Comment: @RussellC. which version of socket.io are you using?

Comment: @MehulPrajapati I put a timeout but it still doesn't work

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande 1.7.3

Comment: @RussellC. we need to spam a bit so we can go to chat.

Comment: The provided code is working, there's something else going on.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande If you mean spam the chat div multiple times I've done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analizing your code (OP provide full code via chat) I found the problem.

You have multiple socket.io connections in the client side, each `var socket = io();` creates a new connection and a new socket id.

You were joining the room using this code:

```
var socket = io();
$("#form-send-message").submit(function () {
     var messageDetails = {
        sender: "<%=currentUser.username%>",
        recipient: $(this).find("textarea").val(),
        message: $(this).find(".chat-message-input").val()
    }
    socket.emit("chat message", messageDetails);
    $(".chat-message-input").val("");
    return false;
});
```

And then you expected the `io.in(room).emit` from the server to enter `"chat message"` listener, when you were overriding the socket and creating a new connection, the new socket never joined the room.

```
var socket = io(); //A new connection, a complete different socket

//This socket never joined the room

socket.on("chat message", function(msg) {
    alert("received message");
    console.log(msg.message);
    if (msg[message] != "") {
        $(".chat-history-div").append($("<li>").text(msg.message));
    }
});
```

**You should only have 1 single connection.**

So to fix your issue:

```
var socket = io();
$("#form-send-message").submit(function () {
     var messageDetails = {
        sender: "<%=currentUser.username%>",
        recipient: $(this).find("textarea").val(),
        message: $(this).find(".chat-message-input").val()
    }
    socket.emit("chat message", messageDetails);
    $(".chat-message-input").val("");
    return false;
});

socket.on("chat message", function(msg) {
    alert("received message");
    console.log(msg[message]);
    if (msg[message] != "") {
        $(".chat-history-div").append($("<li>").text(msg.message));
    }
});
```